# joomla custom component - add rich text support

Tags: joomla, components, custom-component, rich-text-editor, joomla1.6

I am developing a cusom component and I would like it to support rich text fields. Possibly the same way it is done in `com_content`.

in the form definition I have the following field:

```
<field
        name="description"
        type="editor"
        label="COM_MYCOMPONENT_DESCRIPTION_LABEL"
        description="COM_MYCOMPONENT_DESCRIPTION_DESC"
        class="inputbox"
        filter="MyComponentHelper::filterText"
        buttons="true"
    />
```

So basically what happens is that the editor appears as it is supposed to but the text is saved without formatting.
The `MyComponentHelper::filterText` method was added later after investigating `com_content` and copying the `filterText` method to my helper, but it did not work either with or without the line. I even tried to use `ContentHelper::filterText` but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this was my bad. As I have followed the tutorial `MyComponenetHelper` ended up as an abstract class. I made it a normal class and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In joomla 1.5, you had to do this in the model (in function that does the saving):

```
$data['description'] = JRequest::getVar('description', '', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);

if (!$row->bind($data)) {
   ...
```

Don't know if it still exists in Joomla 1.6. Hope it helps.

Comment: this is proper way of doing it! Have to use JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW in JRequest::getVar.